# Reshape my input from 2 dimension to 1 dimension

Tags: matlab, reshape

I tried the code below, but it's not working. I have implemented moving window with my inputs. Now **I want to reshape X_new to one dimension.**

```
X = sixsignals;%input
T= output;%Ouptput                                                                                                                                                                    
%moving data window
 window_size = 20;
X_new = zeros(20, 6, size(X,2) - window_size + 1);
 T_new = zeros(1, size(X,2) - window_size + 1);
 for i = 1:(size(X,2) - window_size +1)
 X_new(:,:,i) = X(:,i:i+19)';
 T_new(i) = T(i+19);
 end
```

Comment: Have you tried `X_new(:)`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have data in more than two dimension where one of the dimensions is 1 (e.g. 5x1x9) then you should use the `squeeze` function which remove the implicit dimension. In this case, that would mean it resizes your output to 5x9.